# Markov Chains examples

Tags: markov-process

So I've been given four examples of stochastic processes, and asked which are Markov chains:

The four examples are henceforth:

- "Keep rolling a die and let $X_n$ be the value of the n-th roll."
- "Keep tossing a coin, let $X_n$ be the number of heads so far."
- "Let $X_0$ $=$ $X_1$ $=$ $1$ and then for each $i$ $\geq$ $2$ toss a coin and either let $X_i$ $=$ $X_{i-1}$ $+$ $X_{i-2}$ [heads] or $X_i$ $=$ $0$ [tails]"
- "Suppose you number all the websites in the world now 0,1,2,...,N. Let $X_t$ be the website you are currently on. You roll a die and if the answer is $6$ then pick a random site to visit $\in$ $[0,N]$ otherwise browse to a new site by clicking one of the current page's links (equiprobably). Call this next site $X_{t+1}$."

The only one I can see clearly isn't a Markov chain is Example 3, as to determine $X_i$ you need to know $X_{i-1}$ and $X_{i-2}$; so only knowing $X_{i-1}$ is not sufficient. Apparently you can also check is using the definition of the Markov property. But I'm not sure how to do this.

I'm quite new to this topic, but a bit confused, if anyone could help me out. I think that Examples 1 and 2 are Markov Chains, but I wouldn't know how to explain explicitly why. And Example 4 I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - "Keep rolling a die and let $X_n$ be the value of the n-th roll."

Whereas the probability of the value of the (n+1)-th roll don't depend on the previous roll (no chain), knowing the full history is not helpful, too. Something as "useless Markov chain."

> - "Keep tossing a coin, let $X_n$ be the number of heads so far."

The prediction of the *"number of heads so far"* after the (n+1)-th toss **depends fully** on the  *"number of heads so far"* after the previous toss.

> - "Let $X_0$ $=$ $X_1$ $=$ $1$ and then for each $i$ $\geq$ $2$ toss a coin and either let $X_i$ $=$ $X_{i-1}$ $+$ $X_{i-2}$ [heads] or $X_i$
>   $=$ $0$ [tails]"

You answered it correctly.

> - "Suppose you number all the websites in the world now 0,1,2,...,N. Let $X_t$ be the website you are currently on. You roll a die and if
>   the answer is $6$ then pick a random site to visit $\in$ $[0,N]$
>   otherwise browse to a new site by clicking one of the current page's
>   links (equiprobably). Call this next site $X_{t+1}$."

The prediction of $X_{t+1}$ **depends only** on $X_t$ (the previous history don't matter).

So the answers are **yes, yes, no, yes,** respectively.